# How to remove elements from array satisfying condition

Tags: javascript

I want to delete json elements which are satisfying the condition. For that I used the given code

```
var index = -1;
for (var i = 0; i < data.dashLayout.dashlets.length; i++) {
  if (data.dashLayout.dashlets[i].rowNo == selectedrowno) {
    if (index == -1 || data.dashLayout.dashlets[i].rowNo < data.dashLayout.dashlets[index].rowNo) {
      index = i;
    }
  }
if (index != -1) {
       data.dashLayout.dashlets.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

But iteration is not completing because the `data.dashLayout.dashlets.length` is reducing with splice. How can I solve this issue? I want to delete all items that are satisfying the condition. Please help

Comment: Loop backwards. Or adjust `i` inside the `if` that does the `.splice()`. (Also, there's no JSON in your code: JSON is a string format. What you have is objects and an array.)

Comment: @nnnnnn looping backwards is definitely the easier option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you split the array in the loop .the array will be reducing you should not iterate fully , so you have to think different idea . so my solution is  you have to store the index based on that you have to remove the array .In the mean time every time the index will be changed so you have to use -1

```
var index = -1;
var arr = []  // make array
for (var i = 0; i < data.dashLayout.dashlets.length; i++) {
    if (data.dashLayout.dashlets[i].rowNo == selectedrowno) {
        if (index == -1 || data.dashLayout.dashlets[i].rowNo < data.dashLayout.dashlets[index].rowNo) {
            index = i;
        }
    }
    if (index != -1) {
        // data.dashLayout.dashlets.splice(index, 1);

        arr.push(index);  //stored it
    }
}

// to remove 

for(var i in arr){
    if (i == 0) {
        data.dashLayout.dashlets.splice(arr[i], 1); // to remove init
    } else {
        data.dashLayout.dashlets.splice(arr[i] - 1, 1); // now index is changed now use -1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another two solutions

```
var a = [2,5,8,13,9,1,4,8,10], l = a.length, c = 5;

// using reverse loop
while(l--){
    if(a[l] < c) a.splice(l, 1);
}

// using filter 
var b = a.filter(function(e, c) {
    return --e > c;
});

console.log(a); // [5, 8, 13, 9, 8, 10]  
console.log(b); // [5, 8, 13, 9, 8, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the filter method of the Array object. Filter method will return a new array which only contains the elements you want. Please see [the definition of the filter method here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

The usage will be like the code below

```
var newDashlets = data.dashLayout.dashlets.filter(function(dashlet, i) {

    // Here your code returns true if you want to keep dashlet. 
    // Return false if you don't want it.

});
```

Answer (score 0):

in jquery

```
data.dashLayout.dashlets = $.grep(data.dashLayout.dashlets, function (dashList, indexpos) {
    if (dashList.rowNo == selectedrowno) {
        if (dashList.rowNo < data.dashLayout.dashlets[index].rowNo || index == -1) {
            index = indexpos;
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using map in jquery

```
data.dashLayout.dashlets = $.map(data.dashLayout.dashlets, function (dashList, indexpos) {
     if (dashList.rowNo == selectedrowno) {
         if (dashList.rowNo < data.dashLayout.dashlets[index].rowNo || index == -1) {
             index = indexpos;
         } else {
             return dashList;
         }
     }
 });
```